# Speed of L2 Regularization on Pytorch

Tags: performance, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to manually implement L2 regularisation and a couple of its variations in a neural network. What I'm doing is the following:

```
for name, param in model.state_dict():
    if 'weight' in name:
        l2_reg += torch.sum(param**2)

loss = cross_entropy(outputs, labels) + 0.0001*l2_reg
```

Is this equivalent to adding 'weight_decay = 0.0001' inside my optimizer? i.e.:

```
torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate , momentum=0.9, weight_decay = 0.0001)
```

My problem is that I thought they were equivalent, but the manual procedure is about 100x slower than adding 'weight_decay = 0.0001'. Why is that? How can I fix it?

Note that I need to also implement my own variation of L2 regularization, so just adding 'weight_decay = 0.0001' won't help.

Comment: Are you sure those are equivalent?

Comment: No, I'm not. I've also tried with torch.norm(param)**2, but it is also way slower than adding "weight_decay = lambda" inside the SGD function. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [PyTorch implementation of SGD](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD) to get some tips and base off of that code.

There are a few things going on which should speed up your custom regularization.
Below is a cleaned version (a little pseudo-code, refer to original) of the parts we are interested in:

```
for p in group['params']:
    if p.grad is None:
        continue
    d_p = p.grad.data
    if weight_decay != 0:
        d_p.add_(weight_decay, p.data)

    p.data.add_(-group['lr'], d_p)

return loss
```

BTW. It seems your implementation is mathematically sound (correct me if I missed anything) and equivalent to PyTorch but will be slow indeed.

### Modify only gradient

Please notice you perform regularization explicitly during forward pass. This takes a lot of time, more or less because:

- take parameters and iterate over them
- take it to the power of `2`
- sum all of them
- add to variable containing all previous parameters (all this while creating graph dynamically and creating new nodes).

What `pytorch` does is it only focuses on backward pass as that's all is needed. This is pretty handy because:

- parameters have to be loaded and iterated over once anyway during corrections performed by optimizer (in your case they are taken out twice)
- no power of `2` because gradient of `w**2` is simply `2*w` (`2` is further left out and `L2` is often expressed as `1/2 * w **2` to make it simpler and a little faster)
- no accumulation and creation of additional graph nodes

Essentially, this line:

```
d_p.add_(weight_decay, p.data)
```

Modifies the gradient adding `p.data` (weight) multiplied by `weight_decay` all done in-place (notice `d_p.add_`), which is all you have to do to perform `L2` regularization.

Finally this line:

```
p.data.add_(-group['lr'], d_p)
```

Updates weights with gradient (modified by weight decay) using standard SGD formula (once again, in-place to be as fast as possible, at least on Python level).

### Your own implementation

I would advise you to follow similar logic for your own regularization if you want to make it faster.

You can copy `PyTorch` implementation of `SGD` and only change this one relevant line. This would also gives you functionality of PyTorch optimizer in case you need it in your experiments.

For `L1` regularization (`|w|` instead of `w**2`) you would have to calculate the derivative of it (which is `1` for positive case, `-1` for negative and undefined for `0` (we can't have that so it should be zero)).

With that in mind we can write the `weight_decay` like this:

```
if weight_decay != 0:
    d_p.add_(weight_decay, torch.sign(p.data))
```

`torch.sign` returns `1` for positive values and `-1` for negative and `0` for... yeah, `0`.

Hope this helps, exact implementation is left for you (hit me up in the comments in case you have any questions or troubles).