# SGD and Adam with Weight Decay are the Same as L2 Regularization in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, regularized

For a loss function $f(\theta)$, L2 regularization is given by:

$$\text{L} = f(\theta) + \frac{\lambda}{2}{\theta}^2$$

The parameter update can then be given by:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} =\theta -  \alpha \frac{\partial f(\theta)}{\partial \theta} - \alpha {\lambda}{\theta}$$

where $\alpha$ is our learning rate. Now, for weight decay, the parameter update rule is given by

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} =\theta -  \alpha \frac{\partial f(\theta)}{\partial \theta} -  {\lambda^{'}}{\theta}$$

For SGD, L2 regularization and weight decay are identical (more specifically when $\lambda = \frac{\lambda^{'}}{\alpha}$, as best explained in in @tTs's answer [[1]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29130/difference-between-neural-net-weight-decay-and-learning-rate)). However, for optimizers such as Adam (see [[1]](https://benihime91.github.io/blog/machinelearning/deeplearning/python3.x/tensorflow2.x/2020/10/08/adamW.html) and [[3]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05101.pdf) for more in-depth explanations), it is well-known that L2 regularization is not equivalent to weight decay. This is also the case for SGD with momentum.

Currently, I am trying to implement L2 regularization for a vanilla neural network in PyTorch. I am experimenting with SGD (with and without momentum) and Adam. Instead of modifying the loss function at each iteration by looping over all the model parameters, I am instead trying to modify only the gradient update rule in the optimiser class to match with the gradient update rule given in the second equation above (similar to @Szymon Maszke's response in [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215600/speed-of-l2-regularization-on-pytorch)). However, despite other questions such as [[5]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478398/how-does-adamw-weight-decay-works-for-l2-regularization) suggesting that the weight decay implementation for SGD/Adam is not the same as L2 regularization, it seems that the current PyTorch implementation **is** actually equivalent to L2 regularization (the code snippets for the relevant parts for SGD and [Adam](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/optim/adam.py) in PyTorch are posted below).

So my **question** is to just confirm my doubts about:

L2 regularization and weight decay actually being the **same** in the current implementation in PyTorch.

Code snippets:

PyTorch's Adam: (line 314 [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/optim/adam.py#L314))

```py
def _single_tensor_adam(params: List[Tensor],
                        grads: List[Tensor],
                        exp_avgs: List[Tensor],
                        exp_avg_sqs: List[Tensor],
                        max_exp_avg_sqs: List[Tensor],
                        state_steps: List[Tensor],
                        grad_scale: Optional[Tensor],
                        found_inf: Optional[Tensor],
                        *,
                        amsgrad: bool,
                        beta1: float,
                        beta2: float,
                        lr: float,
                        weight_decay: float,
                        eps: float,
                        maximize: bool,
                        capturable: bool,
                        differentiable: bool):

    assert grad_scale is None and found_inf is None

    for i, param in enumerate(params):

        grad = grads[i] if not maximize else -grads[i]
        exp_avg = exp_avgs[i]
        exp_avg_sq = exp_avg_sqs[i]
        step_t = state_steps[i]

        if capturable:
            assert param.is_cuda and step_t.is_cuda, "If capturable=True, params and state_steps must be CUDA tensors."

        # update step
        step_t += 1

        if weight_decay != 0:
            grad = grad.add(param, alpha=weight_decay)

        if torch.is_complex(param):
            grad = torch.view_as_real(grad)
            exp_avg = torch.view_as_real(exp_avg)
            exp_avg_sq = torch.view_as_real(exp_avg_sq)
            param = torch.view_as_real(param)

        # Decay the first and second moment running average coefficient
        exp_avg.mul_(beta1).add_(grad, alpha=1 - beta1)
        exp_avg_sq.mul_(beta2).addcmul_(grad, grad.conj(), value=1 - beta2)
...
```

PyTorch's SGD (line 232 [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/optim/sgd.py#L232)):

```py
def _single_tensor_sgd(params: List[Tensor],
                       d_p_list: List[Tensor],
                       momentum_buffer_list: List[Optional[Tensor]],
                       *,
                       weight_decay: float,
                       momentum: float,
                       lr: float,
                       dampening: float,
                       nesterov: bool,
                       maximize: bool,
                       has_sparse_grad: bool):

    for i, param in enumerate(params):
        d_p = d_p_list[i] if not maximize else -d_p_list[i]

        if weight_decay != 0:
            d_p = d_p.add(param, alpha=weight_decay)

        if momentum != 0:
            buf = momentum_buffer_list[i]

            if buf is None:
                buf = torch.clone(d_p).detach()
                momentum_buffer_list[i] = buf
            else:
                buf.mul_(momentum).add_(d_p, alpha=1 - dampening)

            if nesterov:
                d_p = d_p.add(buf, alpha=momentum)
            else:
                d_p = buf

        param.add_(d_p, alpha=-lr)
```

P.S. Seems like I can't embed images for the equations because I don't have enough reputation :/